# Automatically drop FK's to re-create a table and then automatically put the FK's back

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, tsql

I have a number of incidents where SSMS tells me table recreation is required, even for something simple like making a column nullable.  If this table is referenced by FK's, I would ideally like to find a way of temporarily removing those FK's from the 'other' tables, re-creating my table, and then re-creating the FK's on the other table again.

Is there a known way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling won't work in this case.

I'd probably do this:

1. use the SSMS GUI to make my changes

   - save the script: do not execute it
   - run this section by section
   - use a compare tool to generate a better script (eg Red Gate)

Step 4 is optional and you pimp the script from step 2/3 instead